# Virtual keyboard not showing in iOS simulator VS Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

The virtual keyboard in the simulator is not showing when I focus on a text field.
It showed the first time I clicked inside the text field but subsequent clicks in the text field do not bring up the virtual keyboard.
This is happening for the IPhone 6 to iPhone X simulators.

I'm using Visual Studio Mac.
It would appear the simulator detected my Macs keyboard, so it no longer shows the virtual keyboard.

How can I fix this so that the virtual keyboard shows whenever I interact with a control that accepts text input.

**Solution**

In the top menu bar of the simulator I had to turn "Connect Hardware Keyboard" off.
I got there by going to Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

Comment: in iOS Simulator, there is a menu command to toggle the keyboard.  You may have accidentally turned it off

Comment: @Jason Where exactly? I looked through all of the keyboard settings in iOS and didn't see anything that would allow me to toggle the keyboard.

Comment: Not inside iOS, it’s in the menu bar of the simulator application itself

Comment: @Jason Got it thanks!. Had to go to Hardware -> Keyboard -> and deselect "Connect Hardware Keyboard"